# How to add Search Index in elasticsearch document django?

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-rest-framework, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-dsl

I want to implement elasticsearch to search through the name field in the profiles. Suppose there are two users Hariharasudhan and Harish.

Search query **Hari** should give me two users **Hariharasudhan and Harish**

Search query **Harish** should give me **only Harish**

But my code is returning two users for Harish also. I think it is because the search query is also using the edge_ngram tokenizer declared.

I need help to resolve this issue.

Suppose the url localhost:8000/profiles points to the viewset.

> Then localhost:8000/profiles/?search=Hari => should return both
>   Hariharasudhan and Harish.
>
> localhost:8000/profiles/?search=Harish => should return only Harish.

That is, it should perform query similar to name__contains, using edge_ngram.

My elastic search document :

```
from django.conf import settings
from django_elasticsearch_dsl import Document, Index, fields
from elasticsearch_dsl import analyzer, tokenizer

from profiles.models import UserProfile

#Signals
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver

from django_elasticsearch_dsl.registries import registry


# Name of the Elasticsearch index
INDEX = Index('profiles')

# See Elasticsearch Indices API reference for available settings
INDEX.settings(
    number_of_shards=1,
    number_of_replicas=1,
    max_ngram_diff = 50,   
)

html_strip = analyzer(
    'html_strip',
    # tokenizer="standard",
    tokenizer=tokenizer('serializer','edge_ngram', min_gram=3, max_gram=6),
    filter=[ "lowercase"],
)


@INDEX.doc_type
class ProfilesDocument(Document):
    """User Profiles Elasticsearch document."""

    id = fields.IntegerField(attr='id')

    name = fields.TextField(analyzer=html_strip)

    email = fields.TextField(analyzer=html_strip)

    user_details = fields.ObjectField(
        attr = "user_details",
        properties ={
            "nickname" : fields.TextField(),
            "date_of_birth" : fields.DateField(),
            "roll_no" : fields.TextField(),
            "course" : fields.TextField(),
            "department" : fields.TextField(analyzer='keyword'),
            "batch" : fields.TextField(analyzer='keyword'),
            "gender" : fields.TextField(),
            "current_location" : fields.TextField(),
            "work_title" : fields.TextField(),
            "company_name" : fields.TextField(),
            "work_industry" : fields.TextField(),
        }
    )
    user_image = fields.ObjectField(
        attr="user_image",
        properties = {
            'image' : fields.FileField(attr='image')    
        }
    )

    class Django(object):
        """Inner nested class Django."""
        model = UserProfile # The model associate with this Document

@receiver(post_save)
def update_document(sender, **kwargs):
    """Update document on added/changed records.
    """
    app_label = sender._meta.app_label
    model_name = sender._meta.model_name
    instance = kwargs['instance']

    print(model_name)

    if app_label == 'profiles':
        if model_name=='userdetails' or model_name=='userprofileimage':
            registry.update(instance.user_profile)
```

**Serializer :**

```
import json

from rest_framework import serializers
from django_elasticsearch_dsl_drf.serializers import DocumentSerializer

from search_indexes.documents.profiles import ProfilesDocument

class ProfilesDocumentSerializer(DocumentSerializer):
    """Serializer for the Profiles document."""

    class Meta(object):
        """Meta options."""

        # Specify the correspondent document class
        document = ProfilesDocument

        # List the serializer fields. Note, that the order of the fields
        # is preserved in the ViewSet.
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'email',
            'user_details',
            'user_image',
        )
```

**Viewset :**

```
from django_elasticsearch_dsl_drf.constants import (
    LOOKUP_FILTER_TERM,
    LOOKUP_FILTER_TERMS,
    LOOKUP_FILTER_RANGE,
    LOOKUP_FILTER_PREFIX,
    LOOKUP_FILTER_WILDCARD,
    LOOKUP_QUERY_IN,
    LOOKUP_QUERY_CONTAINS,
    LOOKUP_QUERY_GT,
    LOOKUP_QUERY_GTE,
    LOOKUP_QUERY_LT,
    LOOKUP_QUERY_LTE,
    LOOKUP_QUERY_EXCLUDE,
)
from django_elasticsearch_dsl_drf.filter_backends import (
    FilteringFilterBackend,
    IdsFilterBackend,
    OrderingFilterBackend,
    DefaultOrderingFilterBackend,
    CompoundSearchFilterBackend,
)
from django_elasticsearch_dsl_drf.viewsets import BaseDocumentViewSet
from search_indexes.pagination import StandardResultsSetPagination

from search_indexes.documents.profiles import ProfilesDocument
from search_indexes.serializers.profiles import ProfilesDocumentSerializer


class ProfilesDocumentView(BaseDocumentViewSet):
    """The Profiles Document view."""

    document = ProfilesDocument
    serializer_class = ProfilesDocumentSerializer
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
    lookup_field = 'id'

    filter_backends = [
        FilteringFilterBackend,
        IdsFilterBackend,
        OrderingFilterBackend,
        DefaultOrderingFilterBackend,
        CompoundSearchFilterBackend,
    ]

    # Define search fields
    search_fields = (
        'name',
    )

    # Define filter fields
    filter_fields = {
        'name': {
            'field': 'name',
            # Note, that we limit the lookups of `tags` field in
            # this example, to `terms, `prefix`, `wildcard`, `in` and
            # `exclude` filters.
            'lookups': [
                LOOKUP_FILTER_TERM,
                LOOKUP_FILTER_TERMS,
                LOOKUP_FILTER_PREFIX,
                LOOKUP_FILTER_WILDCARD,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_CONTAINS,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_IN,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_EXCLUDE,
            ],
        },

        'department': {
            'field': 'user_details.department',
            # Note, that we limit the lookups of `tags` field in
            # this example, to `terms, `prefix`, `wildcard`, `in` and
            # `exclude` filters.
            'lookups': [
                LOOKUP_FILTER_TERM,
                LOOKUP_FILTER_PREFIX,
                LOOKUP_FILTER_WILDCARD,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_CONTAINS,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_IN,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_EXCLUDE,
            ],
        },

        'batch': {
            'field': 'user_details.batch',
            # Note, that we limit the lookups of `tags` field in
            # this example, to `terms, `prefix`, `wildcard`, `in` and
            # `exclude` filters.
            'lookups': [
                LOOKUP_FILTER_TERM,
                LOOKUP_FILTER_PREFIX,
                LOOKUP_FILTER_WILDCARD,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_CONTAINS,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_IN,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_EXCLUDE,
            ],
        },

    }
    # Define ordering fields
    ordering_fields = {
        # 'name' : 'user.name',
        # 'department' : 'user_details.department',
        # 'title': 'title.raw',
        # 'price': 'price.raw',
        # 'state': 'state.raw',
        # 'publication_date': 'publication_date',
    }
    # Specify default ordering
    ordering = ()
```

Comment: where is the querying logic ? please add it in the question so that somebody can help you

Comment: Hi , have you solved the issue ? if yes, i would appreciate the solution